# Using CURRENT TIME in an insert with a select in DB2

Tags: sql, select, jdbc, insert, db2

I'm using JDBC to insert a single row into a DB2 database table using the insert-select style insert. I am simultaneously trying to insert dynamic data from a variable, as well as the `ENTRY_DATE` using `CURRENT DATE`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (COL_A, COL_B, ENTRY_DATE)
SELECT COL_A, ?, CURRENT DATE FROM mytable
WHERE COL_A > 1;
```

I'm new to sql and JDBC, so I don't know if using `CURRENT DATE` is common, or specific to our system, but it works in a normal insert like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ENTRY_DATE values(CURRENT DATE);
```

I've never used insert-select style inserts, so I don't know if the error is on my '?' which I insert using PreparedStatement.setString, or the `CURRENT DATE` parameter. However I get the following error:

> [BEA][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]STRING TO BE PREPARED CONTAINS INVALID USE
>   OF PARAMETER MARKERS

Do I need to surround either or both of those with something to show they aren't part of the select statement? Do I need to rearrange my statement?

EDIT:

I can't show you my exact code, but here is a close aproximation:

```
String sql = null;
PreparedStatement prepStmnt = null;
Connection conn = getConnection("database");
sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE ";
sql += "(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, ENTRY_DATE)";
sql += "SELECT COLUMN_A, ?, CURRENT DATE";
sql += "FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN_A > 1;";
prepStmnt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStmnt.setString(1, myVar);
prepStmnt.execute();
```

Comment: The problem is with the `?` and not with `CURRENT DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that DB2 doesn't know anything about your parameter which is in the column list of the select, so can't know what the select will return, and so it can't prepare the statement properly.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (COL_A, COL_B, ENTRY_DATE)
SELECT COL_A, CAST(? AS CHAR(1)), CURRENT DATE FROM mytable
WHERE COL_A > 1;
```

Replace the `CHAR(1)` with whatever the correct datatype for `COL_B` is.

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to `?` not to CURRENT DATE.  Maybe this is what you wanted?

```
INSERT INTO mytable (COL_A, COL_B, ENTRY_DATE)
SELECT COL_A, NULL, CURRENT DATE FROM mytable
WHERE COL_A > 1;
```

In DB2 a `?` means there will be a parameter passed for that location.  But it is saying you can't use a Parameter Marker.  So remove the `?` which is the parameter marker.

Comment: So how would he/she then accomplish the "*simultaneously trying to insert dynamic data from a variable*" part?

Comment: Thanks! But I do need to insert dynamic data. My end goal is simply to be able to insert a new row while copying the vast majority of the data from a row on the same table. It's a table with 50+ columns and I only need to change the update_date column with current date, and a different column with a user provided value. If there is another, easier way to do this, I'm open to it! Thanks!

Comment: @CamelCaseBurger - ok, I've no problem with that but then you have to use the parameter marker correctly or you will get an error.  Maybe if you showed us all the code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise defined, the default value for a DATE field is CURRENT DATE.  Therefore you may be able to remove that from your statement:

```
  INSERT INTO mytable
       ( COL_A, COL_B )
  SELECT COL_A, CAST(? AS CHAR(1))
      FROM mytable
      WHERE COL_A > 1;
```